# DFP : How do I display two 300x250 ads in a 640x480 zone?

Tags: google-dfp

I am new to Google DFP, and was wondering...

- I created a 640x480 zone, but I currently don't have an ad to display in it.
- AdSense fills it with a single 300x250 ad.

Is there any way I can display two 300x250 ads in that 640x480 zone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem might be that two 300x250 ads would not fit inside a 640x480 box... they would be too tall so only one will be loaded. This could be the issue, but I'm not sure that google would ever load two ads into a single larger adunit anyway... I don't think there is a way to do this with DFP without some extra coding on your part.

You basically need to have a call back on your 640x480 ad that fires if no matching ads are found and appends two new ad units into it and trys to load ads for them instead.

An easy way to get this call back going would be to use the plugin I made: [jQuery DFP](https://github.com/coop182/jquery.dfp.js)

Take a look at the [bootstrap file](https://github.com/coop182/jquery.dfp.js/blob/master/example-bootstrap.js) to see how to use the callbacks... let me know if you need some example code!

Comment: Thanks Matt for your explanations and resources, sounds interesting. I had a look at your jquery plugin, and bookmarked it. Still discovering DFP and my needs are very basics for now, but if need to step up my game, your plugin could come in handy. Also, it made me realize DFP had it's own API and I could use it with Jquery. Whole new world of possibilities here, I have to wrap my brain around that.

Comment: Yeah my plugin is not really needed if you are just doing basic DFP stuff (although it does make the setup a lot easier), as soon as you get into more complicated uses like needing to know if an ad was found or not it works really well though... anyway good luck with learning DFP, its pretty neat to work with once you figure it out!